# How to stop ruamel.yaml from sorting dict keys?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I am on **Python 3.11** and **ruamel.yaml==0.17.21**

How do I stop ruamel.yaml from sorting the dict keys when doing a dump()?

If I print the dict outright, it shows the keys are ordered as I added them.

But when I dump to file, the keys become alphabetically sorted.

---

**Edit:** Minimal working code:

```py
import sys
from typing import NamedTuple
from pprint import pprint

import ruamel.yaml as ryaml


class Loc(NamedTuple):
    lat: float
    long: float


dadata = {
    "EMEA": {
        "rating": 5,
        "leads": ["Jane", "Jack"],
        "locs": [Loc(3.0, 3.0), Loc(4.0, 4.0), Loc(0, 0)],
    },
    "APAC": {
        "rating": 5,
        "leads": ["Jane", "John"],
        "locs": [Loc(1.0, 1.0), Loc(2.0, 2.0), Loc(0, 0)],
    },
}


class TupleAsFlowSeq(ryaml.Representer):
    def ignore_aliases(self, data):  # type: (Any) -> bool
        return True

    def represent_tuple(self, data):  # type: (Any) -> Any
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            return self.represent_sequence("tag:yaml.org,2002:seq", list(data), flow_style=True)

    def represent_data(self, data):  # type: (Any) -> Any
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            return self.represent_sequence("tag:yaml.org,2002:seq", list(data), flow_style=True)
        return super().represent_data(data)


def main():
    assert all(map(lambda o: isinstance(o, tuple), dadata["APAC"]["locs"]))
    assert all(map(lambda o: isinstance(o, tuple), dadata["EMEA"]["locs"]))
    pprint(dadata, sort_dicts=False)

    yml = ryaml.YAML()
    yml.Representer = TupleAsFlowSeq
    yml.default_flow_style = None
    yml.dump(dadata, sys.stdout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the output:

```
{'EMEA': {'rating': 5,
          'leads': ['Jane', 'Jack'],
          'locs': [Loc(lat=3.0, long=3.0),
                   Loc(lat=4.0, long=4.0),
                   Loc(lat=0, long=0)]},
 'APAC': {'rating': 5,
          'leads': ['Jane', 'John'],
          'locs': [Loc(lat=1.0, long=1.0),
                   Loc(lat=2.0, long=2.0),
                   Loc(lat=0, long=0)]}}
APAC:
  leads:
  - Jane
  - John
  locs:
  - [1.0, 1.0]
  - [2.0, 2.0]
  - [0, 0]
  rating: 5
EMEA:
  leads:
  - Jane
  - Jack
  locs:
  - [3.0, 3.0]
  - [4.0, 4.0]
  - [0, 0]
  rating: 5
```

As you can see, in the ruamel.yaml output, `APAC` comes before `EMEA` while in the data, `EMEA` is first. Also the order of the dict keys in the 2nd level dict changes from `rating, leads, locs` to `leads, locs, rating`

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh I'm supposed to inherit from `RoundTripRepresenter` instead of `Representer`. Okay.

Comment: The `Representer` is inherited from PyYAML 3.X, that one sorts the output.