# How do I force ruamel.yaml's new API to output block style instead of flow style?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I have searched and can't find how to force ruamel.yaml, using new API, to dump my dict in block style.

My code:

```py
    yaml = YAML(typ="safe")
    yaml.Representer = RoundTripRepresenter
    yaml.default_flow_style = False   ### also tried with None
    perfdata: dict[datetime, dict[int, float]] = {}
    performance_file = opts.mapdir / "performance.yaml"

    # This block is just to check if there is previous data
    if performance_file.exists():
        make_backup(performance_file)
        with performance_file.open("rt") as fin:
            perfdata = yaml.load(fin)

    perfdata[datetime.now().astimezone()] = normalized_time_per_row
    with performance_file.open("wt") as fout:
        yaml.dump(perfdata, fout)
```

I've tried:

- Putting `default_flow_style=None` in the `.dump()` call -- error unexpected keyword argument
- `yaml.default_flow_style = None` -- still results in flow style
- `yaml.default_flow_style = False` -- still results in flow style

How do I force it to emit in block style?

---

### Edit to clear up things

I don't care about whether it's "round trip okay". I am NOT looking to "keep the formatting of the input file".

What I really care about is why `yaml.dump()` dumps `perfdata` in flow style, not block style.

Comment: Please explain why you use `yaml.Representer = RoundTripRepresenter`, or where you got the idea from to include that line.

Comment: @Anthon from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74561293/how-to-stop-ruamel-yaml-from-sorting-dict-keys

Comment: A question with zero upvotes is seldom a good example to start with.

Comment: @Anthon eh, he discovered that using the default Representer sorted the keys, so he used RoundTripRepresenter to ensure the keys are not sorted, and you did respond to him. So why not? After all I want the key order to be exactly as I added to the dict, like him.

Comment: Also iirc you responded to him so I'd say it's a good problem and s good answer no matter how many upvotes the question & answer didn't have.

Comment: I respond to many questions that are not good, including yours. Your edit actually made it a bad one. You can of course just try things if you don't have the knowledge to understand a library, and you might get lucky. But overriding the representer (or any of the other stages of loading or dumping) is not what you should do without some better understanding of what you are doing.